# Como exibir listagem do mesmo dado?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou criando um sistema de vendas e gostaria de listar a quantidade vendida de cada produto.
Assim não ficaria repetindo o nome do produto e sim só a quantidade vendida.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A forma que fiz é assim mas gostaria de sugestões .

```
<?php if($_GET['busca'] == "data"){

            $datai = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($_POST['datai']));

            $dataf = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($_POST['dataf']));

            $hora1 = $_POST['hora1'];

            $hora2 = $_POST['hora2'];

            $garcon = $_POST['idGarcon'];



    $query = mysqli_query("SELECT data, nome, preco, SUM(preco) AS pr, SUM(qtd) AS qtd, date_format(data, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data FROM tbl_carrinho WHERE idGarcon='$garcon' AND data BETWEEN '$datai' AND '$dataf' AND time BETWEEN '$hora1' AND '$hora2' GROUP BY data") or die(mysqli_error());



    $sel = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_carrinho")or die(mysqli_error());

        while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

            $ids = $resultado['idGarcon'];

            $oo = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM garcon WHERE idGarcon='$garcon'")or die(mysqli_error());

                    $todos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($oo);

                    $nome_garcon = $todos['nomeGarcon'];

                    $data = $resultado['data'];

                    $nome = $resultado['nome'];

                    $qtd = $resultado['qtd'];

                    $preco_unitario = $resultado['preco'];

                    $precototal = $resultado['pr']; 

                    $total_produto = $qtd * $preco_unitario;

                    $total += $total_produto; 





            $comi = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM config");

            $valor = mysqli_fetch_array($comi);

                $venda = $valor['pgarcon'];

                $ganho += $total_produto * $venda / 100;



            ?>
```

Comment: Se você me explicar como a palavra **tipo** melhorou o entendimento da sua primeira sentença, eu até **tento** ajudar.

Comment: selecionas pelo `idGarcon`, e contas quantos tem, e somas o preço se for o caso

Comment: no meu sistema , eu vendo peixe / caldeirada e etc. e esses dados são enviados para o mysql, como que poderia listar tipo.

Comment: caldeira, 10 unidades, Filé , 12 unidades ,  sem ficar repedindo embaixo do outro várias vezes o nome do produto vendido.

Comment: Pesquise sobre `count` no mysql.

Comment: E só passando os olhos assim muito por alto, faltam ai umas quantas `}` para fechar o `if` ,`while` , a menos que tenha omitido essa parte